# in shopify display variant image on variant picker button

Tags: shopify

I have seen a few solutions but nothing that i can use.

i have a shopify store using Dawn.
product variants names are not user friendly and i do not want to change the variant names.
i want to show the variant image which i know exists.

i think i need a way to reference the variant image. if there is another way to do this I happily appreciate other options.

below is my code. i tried several references for product. products_variant. or variant. but i cannot seem to get the background url to look up the variant image. any help is appreciated. thanks

```
{% comment %}    variant_image_button_v1   {% endcomment %}
      {%  if option.name == "Color" %}
           <label style="background-image:url({{ 'image_url' | url: '200x' }})" 
                 for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
             <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.variant_sold_out_or_unavailable' | t }}</span>
           </label>

        
       {% else  %} 
          <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
            {{ value -}}
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.variant_sold_out_or_unavailable' | t }}</span>
          </label>
       {% endif %}
```